# insert row based on rows height

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range in excel that i want to insert it in ppt slides.

If the rows had a specific height (depending on cell's text value) then i would have no difficulty in inserting i.e. every six rows a new row with specific title columns (= columns' titles of row 1).

Because the rows from 2 to Nth are filled with various wrapped text, the row height is not constant. So, it might be a row with height that alone it covers a ppt slide or it might be a couple of rows that cover a slide.

I don't know if the criteria of inserting a new titled row could be a max fixed height of one or more rows, and if yes, is it possible to give me some guidance?

thanks

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Consider editing it to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm skeptical about that you can set a maximum height for rows (lock rows height) as a default value.. You could [lock a row height](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1130504-can-i-lock-the-size-of-the-cell-so-the-cells-can-be-edited-but-sheet-stays-the-same-size.html) but that implies that the worksheet will be protected (by a password).

What you can do is set a default height value by 
["Changing Default Row Height"](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T005663_Changing_Default_Row_Height.html). This will not prevent other users to increase/decrease the row height.

Another way to easy change all the row heights is to use this code (which could be triggered every time you open/close a workbook):

```
Sub RowHeights()
ActiveSheet.Rows("3:34").RowHeight = 15 'Set row 3 to 34 to RowHeight: 15
End Sub
```